# Android 10: Open an activity using Firebase Message when the app is closed (dead)

Tags: android, android-activity, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-10.0

I have an app that launches an activity on receiving an FCM message. Here is the onMessageReceived:

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        try {
            Trace.v(TAG + "onMessageReceived() from: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

            if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
                String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");

                Trace.v(TAG + "onMessageReceived() message: " + message);
                if (message != null) {
                    mCommandExecutor.execute(message);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Trace.e(TAG, e);
            Analytics.LogEvent("error_logged", "fcm_on_message_received_failed",
                    e.getMessage(), null);
        }
    }
```

It's working in Android 9 devices. On Android 10, I see the message is received and the intent being delivered to the activity (from logcat). But I don't see the activity in the view.

Note: My message is in the data field of the FCM message.

```
form_fields = {}
form_fields[self.FIELD_TO] = registration_id
form_fields[self.FIELD_DATA] = {}
form_fields[self.FIELD_DATA][self.FIELD_DATA_MESSAGE] = message
form_fields[self.FIELD_PRIORITY] = "high"
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Because of restrictions on starting activities from the background on android 10.

Source: [check out here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts?authuser=1)

You should show a notification instead

> In nearly all cases, apps that are in the background should display
> time-sensitive notifications to provide urgent information to the user
> instead of directly starting an activity.